# how to add dotted after 25 character?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using below mention code for restrict attribute character length using substr function

```
foreach ($this->getItemsAsArray() as $item){

            echo '<li '.$item['style'].'><a title ="'.$item['label'].'" class="'.$item['css'].'" href="'.$item['url'].'">'. substr($item['label'],0,25) . '</a><span>' . $item['count'] . '</span></li>';
        }
```

but my problem is i need .. if attribute have more then 25 character i don't know how to add if condition for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use magento default string truncate function.**

Refer this [link](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php#l52-l76)

```
// truncate($string, $length = 80, $etc = '...', &$remainder = '', $breakWords = true)
$remainder = '';
$string = 'Vestibulum lobortis mattis massa. Fusce malesuada mauris -et purus interdum venenatis.';
echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($string, 50, '...', $remainder, true);
// Vestibulum lobortis mattis massa. Fusce malesuada mauris et purus interdum venenatis. Aliquam er...
echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($string, 50, '...', $remainder, false);
// Vestibulum lobortis mattis massa. Fusce malesuada mauris et purus interdum venenatis. Aliquam...
echo $remainder;
// malesuada mauris et purus interdum venenatis.
```

I got this answer from this [url](http://rskuipers.com/entry/magento-string-manipulation)

### Edit :

Use [**strlen**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function.

i.e,

```
$label = (strlen($item['label']) <= 25) ?  substr($item['label'],0,25) : $item['label'];
echo '<li '.$item['style'].'><a title ="'.$item['label'].'" class="'.$item['css'].'" href="'.$item['url'].'">'. $label . '</a><span>' . $item['count'] . '</span></li>';
```

Comment: ya but i don't know how to use that echo condition plz check my question

Comment: @LearningMagento check my update

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: is it right or not (strlen($item['label']) <= 25) ? 'if' echo '$item['label']': 'else' echo '$item['label']'.'...';

Comment: @LearningMagento Check my update

Comment: no it display all the character

Comment: use greater than in the condition `>=`

Comment: Ya i already tried but dotted it will not come only it restrict 25 character